# Como puedo quitar los "."".." de un combobox

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Hola esta duda apenas me surgió ya que desarrollo una Aplicación para comercializar, lo que requiero saber es como quitar esos "." ".." de un combobox en Qt porque al parecer no puedo hacer que pasen por una validacion que retorne un mensaje de error, si no que crashea la Aplicación( por cosas de opencv), entonces alguien me puede ayudar con esta informacion, por favor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como veran en el combobox de "Imagen RGB" tengo ese "." y al abrirlo aparecen ".." y despues el contenido del combobox real que necesito, alguna manera de quitar eso?

Este es el tramo de codigo que uso

```
ui->comboBox_2->setCurrentIndex(-1);
QDir path2("/home/daniel/Imágenes/");
QStringList files2 = path2.entryList(QDir::Dirs);
ui->comboBox_2->addItems(files2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como indica la [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#Filter-enum) tienes que usar el flag `QDir::NoDotAndDotDot` para que se filtren los directorios sin los "."(directorio actual) y ".."(directorio superior):

```cpp
QStringList files2 = path2.entryList(QDir::Dirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
```